# Print() method is not known for class

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a binary search tree. Here is the code I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class BST{
    public:
        int n,*v,vn;
        struct node{
            int val;
            node *left,*right;
            node (int v){ val=v; left=right=0;}
        };
        node *root;

        node *rinsert(node *p,int t){
            if (p==0){
                p=new node(t);
                n++;
            }
            else if (t<p->val){
                p->left=rinsert(p->left,t);

            }
            else if (t>p->val){
                p->right=rinsert(p->right,t);
            }

            return p;
        }

        void traverse(node *p){
            if (p==0) return;
            traverse(p->left);
            v[vn++]=p->val;
            traverse(p->right);

        }
        void print(node *p){
            if (p==NULL) return;
            cout<<p->val;
            traverse(p->left);
            traverse (p->right);
        }

    public:
        BST(int maxelms,int maxval){ root=0;n=0;}
        int size(){ return n;}
        void insert(int v){ root=rinsert(root,v);  }
        void report(int *x){ v=x;vn=0;traverse(root);}
} ;

int main(){
    struct node *root;
    BST bt(12,25);
    bt.insert(12);
    bt.insert(10);
    bt.insert(25);
    bt.insert(7);
    bt.insert(11);
    bt.insert(8);
    bt.insert(4);
    bt.insert(3);
    bt.insert(20);
    bt.insert(23);
    bt.insert(24);
    bt.insert(1);
    bt.Print();

    return 0;
}
```

It doesn't compile: the problem is that the `Print()` method is unknown for the class:

```
1>c:\users\...\bst\bst.cpp(54): error `C3861: 'Print': identifier not found`
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: If you already expect downvotes, why don't you spend a little effort asking a good question?

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. The method has the name `print`, but is called as `Print` at the end.

Comment: it is training  @Joey it is not playing,i need to finish this task

Comment: but print() is  unknown for class

Comment: `print()` takes a `node *`. Try `bt.print(bt.root);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ is case-sensitive. You typed `Print` but the method is called `print`. And, of course, you need to pass that method a node pointer.